# Resetting a Count in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID     num_of_days
1      0
2      0
2      8
2      9
2      10
2      15
3      10
3      20
```

I want to add another column that increments in value only if the `num_of_days` column is divisible by 5 or the `ID` number increases so my end result would look like this:

```
ID     num_of_days    row_num
1      0                    1
2      0                    2
2      8                    2
2      9                    2
2      10                   3
2      15                   4
3      10                   5
3      20                   6
```

Any suggestions?

Edit #1:

`num_of_days` represents the number of days since the customer last saw a doctor between 1 visit and the next.

A customer can see a doctor 1 time or they can see a doctor multiple times.
If it's the first time visiting, the `num_of_days` = 0.

Comment: Why does the first value for `num_of_days` change for id `2` in your expected result set?

Comment: That's the number of days difference between a customer visited and the last time they visited.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the value changes. It *was* 5, but it changes to 2.

Comment: Clarified and fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Based on your question, I'll assume that the combination of `id`/`num_of_days` provides the ordering.

You can use a cumulative sum . . . with `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_id = id and num_of_days % 5 <> 0
                then 0 else 1
           end) over (order by id, num_of_days)
from (select t.*,
             lag(id) over (order by id, num_of_days) as prev_id
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=476d3fdc2fc2822a6012d90030222e94) is a db<>fiddle.

If you have a different ordering column, then just use that in the `order by` clauses.